# preact createPortal renders multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am using preact (a small version of react) in my project.

before updating to preactX version I was using Modal component like this and there was no problem with it, this is how my Modal component looked like:

```
  import { Component } from 'preact';
  import Portal from 'preact-portal';

  export default class Modal extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps({ isOpen }) {
    if (this.state.isOpen !== isOpen) {
      this.setState({ isOpen });
    }
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    const { onClose } = this.props;
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
    onClose && onClose();
  };

  render({ children, closeIcon, isOpen }) {
      return isOpen && (
        <Portal into="body">
          <Wrapper className="notranslate">
            <Overlay />
            <Holder>
              <Close onClick={this.handleClose}>
                <img src={closeIcon || DefaultCloseIcon} alt="Close" />
              </Close>
              {children}
            </Holder>
          </Wrapper>
        </Portal>
      );
   }
 }
```

after upgrading to preactX they dropped out Portal component support and change it to createPortal method like the one in react and here where the problem happenes, it renders whenever the props isOpen changes and because of that modals are opening multiple times.

here is my implementation for modal component with createPortal using hooks:

```
import { createPortal, useState, useEffect, memo } from 'preact/compat';

function Modal({ children, onCloseClick, closeIcon, isOpen }) {
  const [isStateOpen, setIsStateOpen] = useState(isOpen);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isStateOpen != isOpen) {
      setIsStateOpen(isOpen);
    }
    return () => {
      setIsStateOpen(false);
    };
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (
    isStateOpen &&
    createPortal(
      <Wrapper>
        <Overlay />
        <Holder>
          <Close onClick={onCloseClick}>
            <img src={closeIcon || DefaultCloseIcon} alt="Close" />
          </Close>
          {children}
        </Holder>
      </Wrapper>,
      document.body
    )
  );
}

export default memo(Modal);
```

and I am using Modal component like that:

```
<App>
  <SomeOtherComponents />
  <Modal
    isOpen={hasModalOpen}
    closeIcon={CloseIcon}
    onCloseClick={cancelModal}
  >
    <div>
       some other content here
    </div>
  </Modal>
</App>
```

the place where I used my Modal components may render multiple times and that makes Modal component renders too, that was fine before when I was using Portal but when I used createPortal it seems createPortal is not recognizing whether if the Modal component is already in the dom or not.

I suppose that the same would happen in react also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding shouldComponentUpdate method to the Modal component.

it seems that the component was rendering whenever any prop changes in the parent component even if isOpen prop hasn't changed.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.isOpen !== nextProps.isOpen;
}
```

**it seems also that createPortal doesn't apply the shallow rendering as the old Portal applies it in versions before preactX**

Answer (score 1):

this isn't a `createPortal` issue, it's your use of Hooks.
I created a demo based on the code you posted, and it was continuously re-rendering because of the "cleanup" callback returned from your `useEffect()` hook. That callback was unnecessary, and removing it fixes the whole demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/preact-createportal-renders-multiple-times-32ehe